# Finding the next working day from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am dealing with the holiday table of a application and I have to find the next working days based on the holiday list in that table .

If the input is a working day, we expect a blank/NULL to be returned, but if it is a holiday, we expect the next working day to be returned.

My holiday table contains below sample data. 
First date column is for startdate and second one is for enddate. Instead of using startdate and enddate for two consecutive holidays. Client have created two separate rows.

Now I have to write a select query which will give the next working days based on that sample data.

Suppose if I am passing '2016-04-20 00:00:00.000' as the conditional date then the query should return '2016-04-22 00:00:00.000' as the working date and there are consecutive two holidays.

```
2016    2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 2016-04-20 00:00:00.000 Test
2016    2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 2016-04-21 00:00:00.000 Test2
2016    2016-04-28 00:00:00.000 2016-04-28 00:00:00.000 Test3
```

Comment: What if you pass `'2016-04-19 00:00:00.000'`? Would you still expect `'2016-04-22 00:00:00.000'`?

Comment: No the query will check if the date is in holiday list range or not .If it is not in holiday list range then it can return blank.Like in the case of '2016-04-19 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: So, if your input is a working day, you expect a blank to be returned, but if it is a holiday, you expect the next working day to be returned?

Comment: Yes Raj that is the actual requirement.

Comment: Why does you holiday table have two date columns?

Comment: first one is for startdate and second one is for enddate.Instead of using startdate and enddate for two consecutive holidays. Client have created two seperate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
--create table holidays(y int, ds datetime, de datetime, hname varchar(10));
--insert into holidays  values
--(2016,'2016-04-20 00:00:00.000','2016-04-20 00:00:00.000','Test'),
--(2016,'2016-04-21 00:00:00.000','2016-04-21 00:00:00.000','Test2'),
--(2016,'2016-04-28 00:00:00.000','2016-04-28 00:00:00.000','Test3'),
--(2016,'2016-04-22 00:00:00.000','2016-04-22 00:00:00.000','Test4')
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getNextDate(@dateToCheck datetime) RETURNS Datetime
AS
BEGIN

 RETURN(
select top 1 dateadd(d,1,de)  from 

(select y,
  MIN(ds) as ds, 
  MAX(ds) as de
from 
 (
  Select 
   *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ds asc) as ranking 
   from holidays
 ) t  
 group by y,(CAST(ds AS INT)-Ranking)
)t
where @dateToCheck BETWEEN ds AND de
)
END
```

**Upon testing:**

```
SELECT dbo.getNextDate('2016-04-23 00:00:00.000')-- returns NULL
SELECT dbo.getNextDate('2016-04-21 00:00:00.000')-- returns 2016-04-23 00:00:00.000
```

<kbd>**[SQL demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dcd6/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Suposing a holidays table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE holidays (
    [year] int,
    [ds] datetime,
    [de] datetime,
    [description] nvarchar(50)
)
```

You can create a function that iterates through dates until it finds the correct one

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getNextDate(@dateToCheck datetime) RETURNS Datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempDate datetime
    SET @tempDate=DATEADD(day,1,@dateToCheck)
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE @tempDate BETWEEN ds AND de)
    BEGIN
        SET @tempDate=DATEADD(day,1,@tempDate)
    END

    RETURN @tempDate
END
```

This is a very rudimentary first aproximation but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the below mentioned code works.This code first makes a calendar table and then excludes Saturday and Sunday from the dates.

```
declare @mn date = (select min(yourdate) from table)
select top 1 a.caldate
from
(
select dateadd(dd,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) - 1,@mn) as caldate
from sys.all_objects
) as a
where a.caldate not in (select cast(yourdate as date) as yourdate from TableA) and datename(dw,a.caldate) not in ('Saturday','Sunday') and a.caldate >= '2016-04-20'
```